# Sync code with load() function

Tags: javascript

The function `myfunction()` assigns elements on the fields to be displayed after the load(). But this is not what is happening. Only works properly if you use setTimeout(function());

How to run the code sync mode?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mydiv').load('page.html');
    myfunction();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your myFunction() runs the load is not yet done.  jQuery.load() accepts a callback function that will run when the load is complete.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mydiv').load('page.html', function() {
        myfunction();
    });    
});
```

Comment: Noticed we provided the same answer. I think you can just add the function name instead of calling it within another anonymous function, i.e. `.load('page.html', myfunction)`